# How to find out the probability to enter a house?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's assume there is $50\%$ of chances to someone's house entry door to be locked. A locksmith has $10$ keys, of which only 2 open the door. What is the probability of someone to enter the house through this door if he (or she) can choose by chance only one key among the ten?

The question also asks to provide the sample space related to this random experiment.

**MY ATTEMPT**

I have obtained the following sample space

\begin{align*}
\Omega := & \{(K_{1},L^{c}),(K_{2},L^{c}),(K_{3},L^{c}),(K_{4},L^{c}),(K_{5},L^{c}),(K_{6},L^{c}),(K_{7},L^{c}),(K_{8},L^{c}),\\
& (K_{9},L^{c}),(K_{10},L^{c}),(K_{1},L),(K_{2},L),(K_{3},L),(K_{4},L),(K_{5},L),(K_{6},L),(K_{7},L),\\
&(K_{8},L),(K_{9},L),(K_{10},L)\}
\end{align*}

Where $K_{i}$ indicates the "choice of the $i$-th key" (for $1\leq i \leq 10$), $L^{c}$ indicates the door is open and $L$ indicates the door is locked. Since there are two keys which open the door, there are twelve cases in which the person can enter the house.

Due to the fact that the outcomes have the same weight, the sought probability is given by

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(E) = \frac{12}{20} = 0.6
\end{align*}

Where $E$ indicates the event "the person has entered the house". Here I have used the fact that the events $K_{i}$ and $L$ are independent.

Hence I'd like to ask: am I on the right track? Is there another way to obtain the right result? Could someone justify/rectify my argument? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer is correct. I would solve the problem the following way: $P(E)=P($house is unlocked$) + P($house is locked$)\cdot P($right key is chosen$) = 1/2 + 1/2\cdot 2/10 = 6/10=0.6$.

Comment: @EuxhenH (+1) I think you should put that in an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is correct although there is a more systematical approach to the problem in hand. Someone entering the house means that either the house is unlocked or the house is locked and the person chooses the right key. In terms of probability this means
$$\begin{array}{crl}P(E) &=& P(house\ is\ unlocked) + P(house\ is\ locked)\cdot P(right\ key\ is\ chosen)\\ &=& \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{2}{10}\\&=& \dfrac{6}{10}\end{array}$$